# how to off sql server owner name that dbo?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

whenever we expand the table list from sql server 2005 then table name shows with owner name. is there anyway out to off the owner name as a result only table name will display in sql server 2005.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, it's not the owner. It's the schema. Since the 2005 version came out, these are [*distinct concepts*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx).

Second, no, I do not believe it's possible to prevent the schemas being shown alongside the table names in Management Studio's Object Explorer (presumably, where you're looking). The *Object Explorer Details* pane does show them in separate columns, so if you just want an alphabetical list of tables without schema names, then you can look/sort the tables there.

---

Thomas - Open *Tools* -> *Options*, and select "SQL Server Object Explorer" in the left hand pane. This is the *only* obvious place where such an option would exist, and **it does not exist**

Comment: so please tell me how can i off the dbo schema name from object explorer.....thanks

Comment: @Thomas: you cannot - and you should not, either

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema Filter Tables->LeftClick->Filter